# Predefined database in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Where predefined database (.db) should add and how to use it in windows phone 8.1 app?
I am not using Silverlight in my app.
I was trying to do something like this

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        CopyDatabase();
    }

private void CopyDatabase()
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        String DBFile = "myDB.sqlite";
        if (!ISF.FileExists(DBFile)) CopyFromContentToStorage(ISF, "Assets/myDB.sqlite", DBFile);

    }
```

It showing that the namespace name IsolatedStorageFile could not be found.
I found those codes in a sample database app for Windows-phone-8.0 and I was trying to do the same thing in Windows-phone-8.1 (without Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

As I see you try to copy the database from *package* to *IsolatedStorage* and you are targeting *WinRT*. The sample code can llok like this:

```cs
private async Task<bool> CopyDatabase()
{
   StorageFolder packageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
   StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
   StorageFile file = await packageFolder.GetFileAsync("Assets/myDB.sqlite");
   await file.CopyAsync(localFolder);
   return true;
}
```

I've written this code from the top of my head, but should work or help you to find the solution. The above is also possible by Uri schemes:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/myDB.sqlite"));
```

More about [Data and Files you will find at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx)